# $|s_{2k}-s_k|<\epsilon$ implies $\{s_k\}$ converges?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

$\{s_k\}$ is a sequence in $\mathbb{R}$.

$\forall\epsilon>0$, $\exists N\in\mathbb{N}$ s.t. $k\geq N$ implies $|s_{2k}-s_k|<\epsilon$.
Then, does $\{s_k\}$ converge or not?
I need a proof. Thanks.

Comment: You may add a tag "sequences-and-series".

Comment: @Landscape thanks. I updated it.

Comment: You are welcome & +1.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It may not converge. For example, let $s_k=1$ when $k=2^n$ for some $n\ge 0$ and let $s_k=0$ otherwise. Then $s_{2k}-s_k=0$ for every $k\ge 1$, and clearly $s_k$ does not converge.

**Edit:** Even if $s_k$ is nonnegative and increasing, it could also diverge to $+\infty$. For example, let $s_1=0$ and $s_k=\log(\log (k))$ for every $k\ge 2$. Then when $k\ge 2$,
$$s_{2k}-s_k=\int_{\log k}^{\log (2k)}\frac{dx}{x}<\frac{\log 2}{\log k}\to 0, $$
as $k\to\infty$. However, $\lim_{k\to\infty}s_k=+\infty$.

Comment: Then, what if there is one more condition : $\{s_k\}$ is monotone?

Comment: How can I know the sequence is bounded?

Comment: @Analysis : Um... you just need to see if it is :P find some upper bound! But if you just say 'how do I know a sequence $a_n$ is bounded', the general criterion is 'find out'.

Comment: @Analysis: Sorry for my mistake. Please see my updated answer.

Comment: @Landscape: Thanks. Now, I understand about this problem.

Comment: @Analysis: You are welcome.

Answer (score 2):

No, it does not. Define your sequence as you wish for odd numbers $k$ and 
extend $s_k=s_{2^lk}.$

Answer (score 0):

Let $k \in \mathbb N$. Write $k$ as $k = k'2^\nu$ with $2 \nmid k'$. Define $s_k := k'$. Then $(s_k) \in {}^{\mathbb N}\mathbb R$ is unbounded, as for example $s_p = p$ for each prime $p$, but we have for every $k$ that $s_{2k} = s_k$, hence your condition is fulfilled.

Comment: I think the standard notation is $\mathbb R^{\mathbb N}$. Why did you put the $\mathbb N$ on the left??